# Angular 7, adding class to component

Tags: angular, css

I want to dynamically append a **blurred** class to my angular components. My app.component.html file looks like this:

```
<app-navbar [ngClass]="{blurred: shouldBlurComponent}"></app-navbar>

<div class="main">
  <div [ngClass]="{blurred: shouldBlurComponent}">
    <app-header></app-header>
  </div>
  <div class="router-outlet">
    <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <app-footer [ngClass]="{blurred: shouldBlurComponent}"></app-footer>
</div>
```

My blurred class looks like this:

```
.blurred {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(90%);
}
```

It produces an effect like this (my layout is destroyed):
[image]
As you can see it works correctly only for **app-header** component because it is wrapped in **div** selectors. Unfortunately similar trick does not work for other components.
I also tried to apply blurred class directly inside of my **app-navbar** and **app-footer** component and it works like it supposed to. 
[image]

How can I add correctly my **blurred** class to my child component from my app.component.html? If it is possible I want to avoid passing it as a parameter.

EDIT: 
app-footer html

```
<footer class="fixed-footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <a>{{'footer.adminContact' | translate}}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      {{'footer.disclamer' | translate}}
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

app-footer ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

app-footer css

```
.fixed-footer{
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #5e5e5e;
  border-color: black;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  border-top:  2px black solid;
  z-index:1;
}
```

EDIT2:
I've made a simple demo [Working demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ww1hmz?file=src/app/app.component.css):

Comment: post the `app-footer` html and ts

Comment: Can you please create demo of it using stackblitz?

Comment: @Justcode I updated my question with a demo

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blurred sounds like a global class, and should be added to the `styles.css` file, or in any other global stylesheet you have in your application.

<strike>The reason it's not working though, is because the elements by default have `display: inline`. Which results that they have no dimensions inside your application, only the child components have dimensions</strike>

Add this to the stylesheet:

```
app-header,
app-footer,
app-navbar {
  display: block;
}
```

The real reason it's not working is because you are using fixed positioning. According to the html specs, whenever an element has a filter, it becomes the new containing block for absolute and fixed position descendants. This means that any child of an element with a filter will be positioned according to the filtered item.

My advice is to have a better look at how to structure your application. Not use float/fixed for your structure. But have a look at display flex, or grid

Also, you should use `filter: blur(5px) grayscale(90%);`. The webkit [prefix](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) is no longer necessary, and this way you support more browsers. If you use the angular cli, you don't need to add prefixes at all, because they get automatically added based on the browser support mentioned in the `.browserslistrc` file

Comment: I updated my question with a demo link. Already tried your solution there and it did not work. Could you take a look?

Comment: Mm, what do you expect? I see everything blurred except the text '
I am not blurred'. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: It destroys my layout. Look at the second picture attached to the question or just remove blurred class from app.component.html in my demo to see the correct layout

Comment: @pokemzok alright, I understand now. Didn't see you were using fixed positioning :) I've updated my answer. It's not an answer you can directly copy though, because it would take too long to rewrite for me. Anyways, bottom line.. rewrite your structure to not use position:fixed

Comment: Solved it using your adivce. Went with flex display. Thanks.

Comment: @pokemzok glad you could make it work, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
.blurred {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(90%);
}
```

add this into style.css

Add **shouldBlurComponent** in (BlurredService) service file. and create function to check

```
checkStatus() {
if (this.BlurredService.shouldBlurComponent) {
      return 'blurred';
    }
}
```

In HTML `[ngClass]="checkStatus()"` Add this one.